# Is there a general notion of asymptotic equivalence of distributions?

Tags: probability-theory

There are many identities like this in probability theory:

$$\sqrt n \overline X_n\to\mathcal N(0, 1)$$
$$n \min(U_1, ... U_n) \to \mathcal E(1)$$

where the arrows indicate convergence in law, and the $U_i$ are uniform on $[0, 1]$. It's tempting to rewrite these as:

$$\overline X_n\sim N(0, \frac 1 n)$$
$$\min(U_1, ... U_n) \sim \mathcal E(n)$$

where the $\sim$ indicates a kind of asymptotic equivalence of distributions.

Is there a general notion  of asymptotic equivalence of probability distributions that captures the above?

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, in Serfling's *Limit Theorems of Mathematical Statistics* one finds $X_n \sim AN(0,\, \sigma^2/n),$ as $n\to\infty,$ which means $\sqrt n X \overset{\mathcal L} \longrightarrow N(0,\sigma^2)$ as $n\to\infty.$ The letters "AN" stand for "asymptotically normal."